# laravel 4: key not being generated with artisan

Tags: laravel, key, laravel-4

When running

> php artisan key:generate

I can see the generated key in my shell, but the variable 'key' in app.php remains empty.

Running on localhost with windows-apache-php 5.4 - mysql.

Never had this problem before with laravel 4 beta version.

Comment: Have the same issue, but the key is being successfully generated in `.env` file, copying it to `app.php` will do the job? I'm using Laravel 5.0

Answer (score 25):

Had the same problem ...

> 1. Opened app.php
> 2. Remove the entry that says 'YourSecretKey!!!'
> 3. Ran 'php artisan key:generate'

Showed me a key in the console, but nothing in `app.php`!

Solution is ... unlike Laravel 3, don't delete the default `YourSecretKey`!!! in `app.php`, just run the command and it will work.

Hope this helps.

Bagwaa

Comment: Yes...that is the difference. In laravel 3 we had to empty the string, in laravel-4 we have to leave the string with something. Thanks Bagwaa.

Answer (score 7):

You should not remove the original key, just go to your project directory and run

```
php artisan key:generate
```

it will work if you don't touch the previous key.

Answer (score 6):

Have the same problem with L6 on Windows with xampp.

1. Remove the cached config `php artisan config:clear`
2. Regenerate key `php artisan key:generate`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped me installing Handesk on CentOS. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The `.env` file needs to contain a line like this:

```
APP_KEY=
```

You don't have to specify a key, but you have to at least provide a `.env` file and also the above line.

Answer (score 4):

first type any 32 character like 'hyhyhGGyhyhyhyhy23hyhy23hyhy23hy' this and then re execute the command in terminal/cmd.

Step 1:

go to app ---> Config --> app.php

step 2:

'key' => '10101010101010101010101010101010', type any 32 digit or character in that place.

step 3:

go to terminal / cmd
& type : "php artisan key:generate"
press enter

step 4:

see the key has been changed :)

[ It is because in Laravel 4 By using "php artisan key:generate" we simply can replace the default key any time. But if it is an empty space it can not be able to hold the place. ]

Enjoy coding :) \m/

Answer (score 1):

The key generator will only update the APP_KEY in the `.env` file.

```
'key' => env('APP_KEY', 'YourSecretKey'),
```

config/app.php this is reading the APP_KEY from your `.env` file. The second parameter is a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this simple steps:

1. Remove the cached config `php artisan config:clear`
2. Remove existing key or ensure that you have this line : `APP_KEY=` on your `.env` file.
3. Regenerate key `php artisan key:generate`

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. From my project directory I noticed I had the .env file, when I opened the project in atom (my code editor) I noticed that file appeared as .env.txt, I removed the .txt part and ran the command. It worked for me.