# The encryption key must be a random string - Laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption, laravel-4

My laravel project suddenly won't work and keeps displaying the following message when trying to access any page.[image]

Any idea what might be wrong?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried changing the 'key' value in your app/config/app.php?

It looks like the system just started making sure you have it set to non default value.

UPDATE:

just updated my own copy of laravel (to 4.2.13) and tried this out - the error is thrown if you leave the key value set to default as I wrote earlier. Simply set it to 32 random character string and you should be good.

Comment: turned out that was the problem. It was changed to 'YourKey!!!!!'.
I followed this solution and it managed to solve it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818804/laravel-4-key-not-being-generated-with-artisan

Comment: The key might have been left this way all the time. The only thing that changed after the update is that now the framework decided to check and throw an exception if you haven't changed the key to something else.

Comment: You can use `php artisan key:generate` to generate a random key for you.