# Terminal not showing executions - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, cpanel

I have uploaded all my files on the server (cpanel). But the issue is when i log onto my server through my terminal, when i ran any command, 
this is what happen like below in the image

[image]

In the terminal, it seems to execute and quit but does not show anything on the terminal

PS: i am able to see that it execute but don't show anything looking at the space beneath after running the command `php artisan:key generate`.  I actually don't know why this could be happening.

This question may not be qualified as an S.O question.

Comment: posible duplicate of :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818804/laravel-4-key-not-being-generated-with-artisan

Comment: @MarkDavydov you would like to remove your comment :). Any command i write behaves the same.

Comment: Have you tried everything that was suggested there?

Comment: you dont seem to understand my question besides my application already has a key @MarkDavydov.  I mean when i also run php artisan migrate, it seems to be executing but appears blank and nothing shows in my database

Comment: Have you tried a different shell? Colors enabled in your shell?

Comment: As @kerbholz said, it might be something with your shell. Try to highlight the blank lines and see if it shows up.

Comment: Stop and restart your server